# Remove right navigation item, while previewing the document

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am doing following code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath, document is opening but right navigation item is not removed.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (url) {
        self.pdf_viewer = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
        [self.pdf_viewer setDelegate:self];
        [self.pdf_viewer presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
     }
}
```

and

```
- (UIViewController *)documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview: (UIDocumentInteractionController *) controller {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On  document is opening , do rightBarButtonItem = nil

```
if (url) {
    self.pdf_viewer = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];
    [self.pdf_viewer setDelegate:self];
    [self.pdf_viewer presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

and after closing document set again button..

Comment: Adding this code will remove default document interaction controllers share button (Right bar button), where left bar button is done button. please help me @Joge, for me its not working.

Comment: which button do wants to delete ?

Comment: I don't want share button (right bar button) in document interaction controller.