# remove the share option from the document interaction controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, document

Is there any way to remove the share option from the document interaction controller preview ? I am using iOS 8. The answer mentioned in the [Remove right navigation item, while previewing the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25079923/remove-right-navigation-item-while-previewing-the-document) is not working for me. For security reasons we want the user to only be able to view the document and not share it with other apps. Is that feasible in iOS ?

Comment: You probably can't use a [`UIActivityViewController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIActivityViewController_Class/) instead, as this would allow you to set excluded activity types. Unfortunately, they didn't include this option in the `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Comment: have you tried traversing subviews and removing the UIBarButtonItem based on it's class?

Comment: no i haven't tried that, thought it might break with any future iOS updates, I might be wrong though

Comment: @Nav : any help for this issue?

Comment: @Nav : have u find any solution?